# Elasticsearch config tweaking with limited memory

Tags: elasticsearch, memory, server, lucene

I have following scenario:

A single machine with 32GB of ram runs Elasticsearch 2.4, there is one index with 5 shards that is 25gb in size.

On that index we are constantly indexing new data, plus doing full-text search queries that check about 95% documents - no aggregations. The instance generates a lot of CPU load - there is no swapping.

My question is: how should I tweak elasticsearch memory usage? (I don't have an option to add another machine at this moment)

Should I assign more memory to ES HEAP like 25GB (going over 50% memory that readme advises to not do do), or should I assign minimal HEAP like 1GB-2GB and assume Lucene will cache all the index in memory since its full-text searches?

Comment: Are those 5 shards primary shards?

Comment: Yes, they are primary shards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now 50% of server memory so 16GB in this case seems to work best for us.